# File upload error - 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, file-upload, titanium-mobile

I'm building an iPhone app using Titanium Mobile and using the HTTPClient. Whenever I post files to production server I get the following response. If I post to postbin.org or my local or staging servers it's okay.

I don't think the error is generated on the iPhone simulator. I think its a server setting or something. I have an app written in CodeIgniter using the "upload" class.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

<html><head>

<title>403 Forbidden</title>

</head><body>

<h1>Forbidden</h1>

<p>You don't have permission to access {my_uri} on this server.</p>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely looks like an Apache mod_security error.  It is usually triggered by a Form submission (Get or Post).

Ask your server administrator to turn off the Apache mod_security module.