# Android MySQL request gives 403 Forbidden Error - why?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a short question... I implemented a mysql request into my android application, which gives me the error, whenever I want to get data from mysql:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /.../example.php
on this server.</p>
<hr>
```

What I am asking myself is, why the request does work over a web browser where I can get all the data from mysql using the same example.php - but the same stuff does not work when I want to get the data from the android application with JSONParser / HttpRequest..

is that an error from the application itself or is there any option my hoster have to change in the php.in? if yes why does the call work with a webbrowser then?

Comment: Have you given it internet access permission

Comment: Is your web browser testing from the same box as the web server? Is it possible that it could be host based access restriction related?

Comment: @xd6_ yes the permission is set

Comment: @fquinner did not really understand - but I am accessing to the .php from a normal browser where it shows me the sql content... but with the application it does not...hmm

Comment: How do you get to know that your app is not given access permissions to the server?

Comment: @Steve, If you are running your php code on the same machine as your browser is running on, your apache server may be set up to allow from localhost, but deny from all other IPs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16688698/wamp-apache-allow-localhost as an example where only localhost access is enabled by default.

Comment: @SajibAcharya via httpResponse 

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

line is giving me the message

Comment: @fquinner i don's use the php on same machine, i am using mysql from a hoster - i am trying to use other hoster ...let's see..

Comment: yes it is working on a different free hosting... i tested it, and it is working... must be some setting that blocks the request..but i don't know what setting, so i could ask my hoster to change the setting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007971/file-upload-error-403-forbidden?rq=1

Comment: I solved that problem... it was because of the .htaccess file, it denied the request :)